# Modifying the margin alignment in gnuplot in multiplot mode

Tags: gnuplot

I have created two plots in multiplot mode using epslatex as output terminal. The y axis labeling is different for both the plots.The first plot's y axis ranges from [0:45] and the second plot's y-axis ranges from [-5e-008 to 4e-007]. Due to the different widths of the y-axis labels, the width of the second plot is less than that of the first plot. I have tried the available scaling options but they do not work. Is it possible to edit the plot so that I can have the same width for both the plots irrespective of the y-axis range?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing can be reproduced by doing something like so:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
plot sin(x)
plot 100000*sin(x)
```

[image]

The left margins are clearly not aligned. To fix this, you can try an explicit definition of where the margins lie:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
set lmargin at screen 0.15
plot sin(x)
plot 100000*sin(x)
```

[image]

If your images are side by side, you can adjust the margins taking the appropriate offset into account:

```
set multiplot layout 1,2
set lmargin at screen 0.15
plot sin(x)
set lmargin at screen 0.5+0.15
plot 100000*sin(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It solved my issue. I have another small query. If you see in the second graph where I have exponential y range, which is occupying more space in the page. I have edited the plot a bit to remove the zeros. However, it look quite big when I have two digits in the exponential for other plots. So I have decided to represent this exponential only once for the y axis range at the top left. I have used label and xlabel with offset but it does not look good. Please suggested through which I can improve the way my plot looks.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to achieve? Something like this: http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/Content/Extras/html/Extras_Plot_05.png ? It might be worth asking a separate question, although some solutions should be available even on this site if I remember correctly.

Comment: yes exactly it is as you have mentioned in the image. However I will raise a new question as you have suggested.